# webpage and images to pdf conversion with watermark

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to convert images requested from the server to the pdf with a watermark on the click of a button. Also if there is a pdf preview functionality available in plugin with disabled user selection and copy option, then it will be the best.

websites' platform is salesforce and we are simply using javascript and jquery in it. we didn't discuss the product price yet. but open to looking at any range of solution. all images requested from the server

Answer (score 0):

so you want a button next to the image, converting it to pdf with image in it and a watermark in picture itself? This can be done quite easy in PHP using gd library and fpdf library on backend.

[gd library watermark](http://programmerblog.net/watermark-images-using-php/)

[fpdf adding image to pdf](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm)